# Starting Informatica as a service using systemd

Tags: systemd

I am trying to start Informatica as a service, so that it starts up automatically on reboot.I am using RHEL 7.5 and Informatica 9.5.1. After reboot, the service starts, the domain and the admin console also start up, but the repository cannot be connected toand hence, the integration service (which could be connected when Informatica was not started as a service, but manually).

**My systemd env file (/etc/systemd/system/informatica.service.d/env.conf)  is as follows:-**

```
Environment=INFA_USER="infa"

#######DB2 Environment
. /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile
Environment=DB2HOME=/home/db2inst1
Environment=DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1
Environment=DB2DIR=/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5
Environment=PATH=/app/infa/server/bin:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin
Environment=LANG=C

#######Informatica Specific Environment
Environment=INFA_HOME=/app/infa
Environment=INFA_DOMAINS_FILE=/app/infa/domains.infa
Environment=ODBCHOME=/app/infa/ODBC7.0
Environment=ODBCINI=/app/infa/ODBC7.0/odbc.ini
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/app/infa/java
Environment=PC_SERVICE=/app/infa/tomcat/bin
Environment=INFA_SHARED=/app/infa/services/shared
Environment=ODBCINST=/app/infa/ODBC7.0/odbcinst.ini
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/infa/tomcat/bin:/app/infa/server/bin:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64:/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/lib64
Environment=HOME=/home/infa
Environment=LANG=en_US.utf8
Environment=NLS_LANG=american_america.UTF8
Environment=INFA_CODEPAGENAME=UTF-8
```

**My systemd(/etc/systemd/system/informatica.service) file is as follows:-**

```
####### Informatica System Service

####### /etc/systemd/system/informatica.system
[Unit]
Description=Informatica Startup Service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
#######systemd ignores PAM limits, so set any necessary limits in the service
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
LimitNOFILE=65535
Type=forking
#######RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=on-failure
User=infa
Group=infa
StandardOutput=console
EnvironmentFile=/etc/systemd/system/informatica.service.d/env.conf
WorkingDirectory=/app/infa/tomcat/bin/
ExecStart=/app/infa/tomcat/bin/infaservice.sh startup
ExecStop=/app/infa/tomcat/bin/infaservice.sh shutdown
ExecReload=/app/infa/tomcat/bin/infaservice.sh shutdown;/app/infa/tomcat/bin/infaservice.sh startup
SyslogIdentifier=Informatica.service

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**The error I get is :-**

```
"Database Driver event...Error occurred loading library [libdb2.so.1:cannot
open shared object file: No such file or directory] Database driver
event...Error occurred loading library [libpmdb2.so]
```

Can someone please help me understand what I might need to change as I am not really familiar with the systemd scripts?

Note:- I have also tried using "PassEnvironment" instead of "Environment" in the env.conf file. Also, although I have mentioned user & group as infa, the service still starts as root.

```
**ps -ef | grep pm**
```

root       3771   3159  0 15:20 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pm

** The status of the Informatica service is as follows:-**

```
# systemctl status informatica
● informatica.service - Informatica Startup Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/informatica.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/informatica.service.d
           └─env.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-09-10 15:50:59 HKT; 16min ago
  Process: 1795 ExecStop=/app/infa/tomcat/bin/infaservice.sh shutdown (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1884 ExecStart=/app/infa/tomcat/bin/infaservice.sh startup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1927 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/informatica.service
           ├─1927 /app/infa/java/bin/java -ea -Djava.awt.headless=true -Duser.dir=/app/infa/tomcat/bin -DINFA_PLUGINS_HOME=/app/infa/plugins -DI...
           └─2100 /app/infa/java/bin/java -XX:GCTimeRatio=9 -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx512M -Dsun.reflect.noInflation=true -d64 -DFrameworksLogFil...

Sep 10 15:50:53 infatest systemd[1]: informatica.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 10 15:50:53 infatest systemd[1]: Starting Informatica Startup Service...
Sep 10 15:50:59 infatest Informatica.service[1884]: Starting Informatica services on node 'node01_infatest'
Sep 10 15:50:59 infatest Informatica.service[1884]: Using CURRENT_DIR:     /app/infa/tomcat/bin
Sep 10 15:50:59 infatest Informatica.service[1884]: Using INFA_HOME:       /app/infa
Sep 10 15:50:59 infatest systemd[1]: Started Informatica Startup Service.
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Regarding your note at the end: the result is not the service, but the `grep` command you used in the attempt to find it. Try `pgrep pm` or, if `pgrep` is not available, `ps -ef | grep [p]m` to avoid the trap of your `ps` + `grep` pipeline finding itself. (The regular expression `[p]m` means exactly the same as `pm`, but the extra brackets ensure the search won't match the command line used to actually perform the search.)

Comment: @telcoM I tried using ps -ef | grep [p]m as     pgrep is not available , but it returned nothing.

Comment: Your service is not "starting as root", it's dying on start-up failure. Find out where the files `libdb2.so.1` and `libpmdb2.so` actually are. Are they in the directories listed in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable? Also, your env file includes the line `. /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile`; since it does not include the `=` sign, it will be completely ignored by systemd. A systemd environment file is supposed to have just `NAME=value` style assignments (without the `Environment=` prefix), and possibly comments, nothing else.

Comment: @telcoM I tried the command `systemctl status informatica` and it is active (running). Please see the original post to view the informatica service status. Thanks.

Comment: @telcoM Also, I just tried removing the `Environment=` prefix and now the service status is failed, and it again shows `active(running)` when I use the prefix.